# Android Intent related

Tags: android

I have an intent open my phone; when something comes from the server from another Java class I want to refresh the current screen. Can you please help me with how I can refresh my current screen without creating a new one?

Answer (score 1):

Check this link out

[On New Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent))

So when you get this ,from inside the method `onCreate` method with whatever data you want and your screen gets refreshed.

Actually you could have been more specific.